# Using M-Test to prove convergence of a sum of discontinuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

[Sorry for the title, I could not describe it better.]

> Define that functions $\phi_n(x): R \rightarrow R$ such that: $\phi_n(x)=nx-n_{nx}$, where $n \geq 1$ is a natural number and $n_{nx}$ is the closest natural number to $nx$.
>
> We now sum this functions $\phi_n$ and create a function with large number of discontinuities:
>   $$
> f(x)=\phi_1(x)+\frac{\phi_2(x)}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_3(x)}{3^2}+\frac{\phi_4(x)}{4^2}+...
> $$
>               Use the Weierstrass M-test to show that series, of right, converges uniformly to $f(x)$ and that consequently:
>               $$
>    \lim_{x \rightarrow {x_0}^{\pm}}f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{\lim_{x \rightarrow {x_0}^{\pm}}{\phi_n(x)}}{2^j}
>    $$

**MY ATTEMPT:**

Let $M_n=1/2^n$ note that, 
$$
\left|\frac{\phi_n(x)}{n^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2^n} = M_n, \forall n \geq 1
$$
since $\left|\phi_n(x)\right|\leq 1$

Futhermore, $\sum_{i=1}^\infty = 1 <\infty$. so, use the M-Test to to get that series converges uniformly.

*I think so far all is ok*

Now the second part:
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow {x_0}^\pm}{f(x)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow {x_0}^\pm} \left( {\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{\phi_j(x)}{2^j}}+\phi_1(x) \right)
$$
**MY QUESTIONS:**

From this I can not get the result proposed by exercise.

There is an error of reasoning on my part or an

Comment: In the definition of $f$, you wrote $n^2$ in the denominator, elsewhere $2^n$. Also, in the title, and the last part of the problem statement, $j$ and $n$ are confounded.

Comment: @DanielFischer this implies that my prove of the first part are wrong, right? :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's wrong. But the wrong part is more "since $\lvert\phi_n(x)\rvert \leq 1$" than any confusion of indices. (I suppose the $\dfrac{\phi_3(x)}{3^2}$ etc. is a plain typo, with that, the sum wouldn't converge.) You have $\phi_n(x) \approx 2nx$, so basically, you have to use the convergence of $\sum \frac{n}{2^n}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer 
But, is not it worth it $\phi_n(x) \leq 1 $?

Can you detail for me what is the part you are talking supposing that is plain typo? Is in the exercise?
$\phi_1(x)+\frac{\phi_2(x)}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_3(x)}{3^2}+\frac{\phi_4(x)}{4^2}+...$ 
is actualy 
$\frac{\phi_1(x)}{2}+\frac{\phi_2(x)}{2^2}+\frac{\phi_3(x)}{2^3}+\frac{\phi_4(x)}{2^4}+...$ ??

Comment: Yes, it should (most likely) be $$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\phi_n(x)}{2^n}$$ (or divide by $2^{n-1}$, which doesn't make a fundamental difference) in the exercise. With denominators $n^2$, the series wouldn't converge (for $x\neq 0$), since $\lvert \phi_n(x)\rvert \geqslant 2n\lvert x\rvert - 1$ grows proportional to $n$. But note that the convergence (with the $2^n$ denominators) is not uniform on all of $\mathbb{R}$, it is only locally uniform, for every $K > 0$, the convergence is uniform on $[-K,K]$ (and that's all you need). The exercise seems to have a couple of serious wrinkles.

Comment: Really it made more sense to me. I was afraid to change it but I think that is the only way to get where I need to get. If I change it the rest it works...

Comment: @DanielFischer I had made a fundamental change in the $\phi$ definition. I made a small typo with serious consequences.

Comment: Ah, that makes indeed $\lvert \phi_n(x)\rvert \leqslant 1$, and you have uniform convergence on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Since it is easy to see that you have the one-sided limit of a finite sum equal to the sum of the one-sided limits of the summands, what remains is to see that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$, then $f(x^+) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x^+)$ and of course the same for $x^-$, where $g(x^\pm)$ denotes the one-sided limit. Have you an idea how you would go about proving that? (Or is it perhaps a theorem you can use, the "consequently" might indicate that.)

Comment: I think it is a direct consequence of the fact that a uniform convergence. This is not the main theme of this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> the closest natural number to $nx$.

This is not a well-defined concept:   if $nx=2.5$, is the closest natural number $2$ or $3$?

Once this is resolved somehow, you can conclude that the difference between $nx$ and that natural number is at most $1/2$. The Weierstrass test applies with $M_n= \dfrac{1 }{2n^2}$.

That limits commute with uniform convergence is easy to show. Let $S$ be the sum of the limits as  $x\to x_0^+$. Given $\epsilon>0$, truncate the series so that the tail is $<\epsilon/2$, find neighborhood where the partial sum is within $\epsilon/2$ from $S$, and conclude that the whole series is within $\epsilon $ of $S$ in this neighborhood. Hence the limit of the sum is $S$.